# Where is terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I have just installed Ubuntu on my mom's Chromebook. I've installed Firefox using xterm, why xterm? Because when I search, look on the app thing where bash home is, and press ctrl+alt+t, terminal is not here. I have no clue why but there's no terminal.

Comment: Have you tried `Terminal` in Dash?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 0):

Open the Dash by clicking on the Ubuntu icon on the upper-left corner of your screen. Then type in "terminal". Select the terminal application from the results.